# Merge Datarow in Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to Merge DataTable rows with somthing like this Data

`A  Ar 1  3
A  Ab 3  4
B  Bl 3  5
B  Bk 5  2
M  Mj 4  5`

to DataTable Like This

```
A Ar 1 3 Ab 3 4
B Bl 3 5 Bk 5 2
M Mj 4 5 Null Null Null
```

is there any TSQL statment for do this?

Comment: Are the number of possible column sets limited to 2 groups (6 cols), or could there be more than 2 rows for `A`, 2 rows for `B`, etc, requiring an unknown number of output columns?

Comment: Michael Berkowski it's just 2 rows, and number of columns is 6 cols

Comment: which  version of sqlserver do you need? if you are  working with sql 2012 there is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough since its a limited number of variables. the first part was just setting up a temp table since i don't know your column names or anything.

```
select 'a' 'c1', 'ar' 'c2', '1' 'c3', '3' 'c4'
into #temp
union select 'a' 'c1', 'ab' 'c2', '3' 'c3', '4' 'c4'
union select 'b' 'c1', 'bl' 'c2', '3' 'c3', '5' 'c4'
union select 'b' 'c1', 'bk' 'c2', '5' 'c3', '2' 'c4'
union select 'm' 'c1', 'mj' 'c2', '4' 'c3', '5' 'c4'


select *
from #temp t1
left join #temp t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1
and t1.c2 != t2.c2
where t1.c2 = (select MAX(c2) from #temp where #temp.c1 = t1.c1)


c1  c2  c3  c4  c1      c2       c3     c4
m   mj  4   5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
b   bl  3   5   b        bk      5       2
a   ar  1   3   a        ab      3       4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
--create temp table for OP data sample 
DECLARE @YourData AS TABLE
    (
      C1 VARCHAR(1) ,
      C2 VARCHAR(2) ,
      C3 INT ,
      C4 INT
    )
INSERT  @YourData
        ( C1, C2, C3, C4 )
VALUES  ( 'A', 'Ar', 1, 3 ),
        ( 'A', 'Ab', 3, 4 ),
        ( 'B', 'Bl', 3, 5 ),
        ( 'B', 'Bk', 5, 2 ),
        ( 'M', 'Mj', 4, 5 ) 
--final query
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   C1 ,
                        C2 ,
                        C3 ,
                        C4 ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY C2 ) AS RN
               FROM     @YourData
             )
    SELECT  c1.C1 ,
            c1.C2 ,
            c1.C3 ,
            c1.C4 ,
            c2.C1 ,
            c2.C2 ,
            c2.C3 ,
            c2.C4 
    FROM    cte AS c1 LEFT JOIN cte AS c2 ON c1.C1 = c2.C1 AND c2.RN > 1
    WHERE c1.rn = 1
```